# MongoDB nested query - BadValue error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```js
{ ownerId: 14,
  '$or': 
   [ { '$or': 
        [ { '$and': 
             [ { provider: 'INSTAGRAM' },
               { tags: 
                  { '$or': 
                     [ { '$in': [ 'skyhotel' ] },
                       { '$or': [ { '$all': ["skyhotel","excellent"] } ] } ] } } ] },
          { '$and': 
             [ { provider: 'VKONTAKTE' },
               { tags: 
                  { '$or': 
                     [ { '$in': [ 'skyhotel' ] },
                       { '$or': [ { '$all': ["skyhotel","excellent"] } ] } ] } } ] } ] },
     { '$or': 
        [ { '$and': 
             [ { provider: 'INSTAGRAM' },
               { authorLogin: { '$in': [ 'valera92', 'petyan' ] } } ] },
          { '$and': 
             [ { provider: 'VKONTAKTE' },
               { authorLogin: { '$in': [ 'valera92' ] } } ] } ] },
     { '$or': 
        [ { '$and': 
             [ { provider: 'INSTAGRAM' },
               { locationId: { '$in': [ '32454234' ] } } ] } ] },
     { '$or': 
        [ { '$and': 
             [ { provider: 'INSTAGRAM' },
               { location: { '$or': [ { '$geoWithin': { '$centerSphere': [ [ '56.829782', '60.593162' ], 0.000012629451881788331 ] } } ] } } ] } ] } ] }
```

It seems to be malformed according to mongo standards. The error I'm getting is:

`Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $or`

What would be the proper way in which I could reformat this query?

EDIT: Document example

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570362332ee1a7ab1ecb9899"),
    "proextid" : "INSTAGRAM_fdfsfsdfsdfwefwef2r3232",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-04-05T06:58:59.683Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-04-05T06:58:59.683Z"),
    "ownerId" : 7,
    "authorId" : "390599885",
    "authorName" : "name",
    "authorLogin" : "login",
    "authorDetail" : {
        "authorPicture" : "url",
        "authorLink" : "url"
    },
    "externalCreatedAt" : ISODate("2015-08-29T22:42:04.000Z"),
    "externalId" : "fdsfsdfsdfsdfwer2342342423423r23r",
    "detailType" : "PHOTO",
    "location" : [ 
        0, 
        0
    ],
    "locationId" : "",
    "locationTitle" : "",
    "provider" : "INSTAGRAM",
    "detail" : {},
    "description" : "hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "ленинградскийпроспект", 
        "москва", 
        "архитектура", 
        "историческоенаследие", 
        "петровскийдворец"
    ],
    "commentsCount" : 1,
    "likesCount" : 40,
    "groupName" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Please present an appropriate use case. At least provide a sample document from the collection and what you want your query to find.

Comment: First of all, I don't really think you need to use $and wherever you've used it. Every thing inside an Object to the find method is implicitly ANDed.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera added an example document. Getting rid of $ands doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: And what is it, that you want to do?

Comment: As far as I can understand what you're trying to do,  `provider: { $in: [ 'INSTAGRAM', 'VKONTAKTE' ] },
                    tags: { $in: [ 'skyhotel', 'excellent' ] }`  would be equivalent to your first element in the `$or` array.

Comment: That's the problem. I'll not be able to explain if you don't tell me what you want the query to do.

Comment: This would probably be better explained by writing down the "words" of what conditions you expect the query to match. You certainly do not need all of this nesting and there is so much that is completely syntactically incorrect it makes the question even more unclear. Words and an both an example document that "should match" and another sample that "should not", with the words explaining why and why not.

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be simplified as something like:

```
{
ownerId:14,
provider: { $in: [ 'INSTAGRAM', 'VKONTAKTE' ] },
'$or': [
    {
        tags: { $in: [ 'skyhotel', 'excellent' ] }
    },
    {
        authorLogin: { $in: [ 'valera92', 'petyan' ] },
    },
    {  
        locationId:{ '$in':[ '32454234' ] }
    },
    {  
        location:{  
                    {  
                        '$geoWithin':{
                            '$centerSphere':[ [ '56.829782', '60.593162' ], 0.000012629451881788331 ]
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
]
}
```

Now this may not be exactly what you're looking for. But from what you asked, and the information you provided, this is the best suggestion I can give.